# Uploading a video to a server with Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, file-upload

I am currently working on a Ionic application and I need to upload a video to my server with the Ionic Native File Transfer Plugin.

For this, I get my video from a GoPro. The downloading works. But I cant' upload the video. I checked, the application does not even connect to the website.

Upload code:

```
upload(){
   let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'file',
      fileName: 'GOPR0061.MP4',
      headers: {}
   }

   var url = "http://mywebsite.com/api/video" ;

   this.fileTransfer.upload(this.video.toURL(), encodeURI(url), options, true)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('It worked!' + data);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('Try again' + err);
    })
 }
```

I did multiples `console.log()` and got this:

- **this.video.toURL() :** `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A724AA9F-A0F6-44B0-9L15-35SC0FD2S1F5/Library/NoCloud/GOPR0061.MP4`
- **encodeURI(url) :** `http://mywebsite.com/api/video`
- **options :** `[object Object]`

We can see that the video file exists and the URL seems good. I have no .htaccess that could block the upload.

So if someone knows how to solve my problem, I would be really grateful!

Comment: Are you getting anything output to the console from your err block?  Also how is your API set up to receive files?

Comment: @MarkD Thank you for your response, it was actually a problem from the server apache configuration. The server was accepting something like 2MB Files (and the video was more).